# Why esc_html_() is not used on every text that has a translation (on Twenty Twenty One)?

Tags: escaping

Why, in the `register_nav_menus()` functions (from Twenty Twenty One functions.php), do we find `esc_html__()` on the primary menu **but not on secondary menu**, like below :

```
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary menu', 'twentytwentyone' ),
            'footer'  => __( 'Secondary menu', 'twentytwentyone' ),
        )
    );
```

I understand that esc_html() "retrieve the translation of $text and escapes it for safe use in HTML output", as explained in WordPress codex, but why is it used on the first menu and not on the second, that's what i cannot figure out.

Is there a specific rule that I missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer appears to be human error. [Originally](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentyone/commit/956a3172a41545ca04a133c034b47ae870a4a9cd), during development, Twenty Twenty One had one menu, registered like this:

```
'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'twentytwentyone' ),
```

Then somebody [went through and added escaping](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentyone/commit/6e99e4d64dad199d21e32c49a81d37762ef9c922) to many `__()` throughout the theme, resulting in this:

```
'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Navigation', 'twentytwentyone' ),
```

Then, later on, [a second menu was added](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentyone/commit/ed3ccb6a57e8e1c60b675d5b78768557f75ce5d6), like this:

```
'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Navigation', 'twentytwentyone' ),
'footer'  => __( 'Footer Navigation', 'twentytwentyone' ),
```

And nobody seems to have noticed the discrepancy.

It's often considered best to escape "late", as described in [this WordPress VIP article](https://wpvip.com/2014/06/20/escaping-output/). That is, as close to output as possible. So it's important to note that these lines are not outputting anything. They are just defining the strings to be output later. *However*, this is where WordPress outputs these values:

```
<label for="locations-<?php echo esc_attr( $location ); ?>"><?php echo $description; ?></label>
```

Note that `$description`, which is the menu name, is *not* escaped. Therefore, since editing WordPress core is not an option, it would be considered best practice to escape the menu name when registering it.

So *should* the secondary menu be escaped. Yes. Is it? No. Why? Human error.

Comment: Thanks for you very clear answer. Do you know where I can report this error ? I wanted to report it to the WordPress team, but I can't find the way to do so : on Github they ask to report it any bug on [core.trac.wordpress.org](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/), but on core.trac.wordpress.org they ask to report any security vulnerability it on [hackerone.com](https://hackerone.com/), where it's not possible to report it.

Comment: Try core.trac.wordpress.org. This isn't remotely serious enough for HackerOne.

Comment: Done ! Thanks :)

Comment: A patch is going to be added : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/54127. I like this process ! Amazed by how fast it is going.